# Plot of the real part of the maximum eigenvalue of matrix

Tags: eigenvalues

I am looking to plot the real part of the maximum eigenvalue of matrix A as a function of x and y.
Thanks

```
A[x_, y_, z_]:={{-6000000 \[Pi] + 12000000 \[Pi] z_, 0, 0, 6000000 \[Pi] y_, 0, 6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0}, {0, -6000000 \[Pi] - 12000000 \[Pi] z_, -6000000 \[Pi] y_, 0, -6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 6000000 \[Pi] y_, -6000000 \[Pi] + 12000000 \[Pi] z_, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6000000 \[Pi] x_}, {-6000000 \[Pi] y_, 0, 0, -6000000 \[Pi] - 12000000 \[Pi] z_, 0, 0, -6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0}, {0, 6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0, -3600000 \[Pi], 0, 0, 0}, {-6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3600000 \[Pi], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0, -3600000 \[Pi], 0}, {0, 0, -6000000 \[Pi] x_, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3600000 \[Pi]}};


maxEigenvalueReal[x_, y_, z_] := Re[Max[Eigenvalues[A[x, y, z]]]];

DensityPlot[maxEigenvalueReal[3, y, z], {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

There should not be any patterns (e.g., `x_`) on the RHS of the definition for `A`

```
A[x_, y_, 
   z_] := {{-6000000 π + 12000000 π z, 0, 0, 6000000 π y, 0, 
    6000000 π x, 0, 
    0}, {0, -6000000 π - 12000000 π z, -6000000 π y, 
    0, -6000000 π x, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    6000000 π y, -6000000 π + 12000000 π z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    6000000 π x}, {-6000000 π y, 0, 
    0, -6000000 π - 12000000 π z, 0, 0, -6000000 π x, 0}, {0, 
    6000000 π x, 0, 0, -3600000 π, 0, 0, 0}, {-6000000 π x, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -3600000 π, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 6000000 π x, 0, 
    0, -3600000 π, 0}, {0, 0, -6000000 π x, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -3600000 π}};

Eigenvalues[A[3, 3, 3]]
```

[image]

Since the [`Eigenvalues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html) are complex, I assume that you want the eigenvalue with the greatest magnitude

```
maxEigenvalueReal[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Re[MaximalBy[Eigenvalues[A[x, y, z]], Abs][[1]]];

DensityPlot[maxEigenvalueReal[3, y, z],
 {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want the eigenvalue with the maximum real part

```
maxEigenvalueReal[x_, y_, z_] := 
  Re[MaximalBy[Eigenvalues[A[x, y, z]], Re][[1]]];

DensityPlot[maxEigenvalueReal[3, y, z],
 {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, dear friend, for your response. Just one more question, please: does this code search for the real value of the maximum eigenvalue and plot it as a function of the variables mentioned here, or should I manually look for the maximum eigenvalue?

Comment: It is meaningless to talk about the maximum of complex numbers, they are not ordered. You need to specify whether you want the maximum magnitude or maximum real part or maximum imaginary part or some other scalar function of complex numbers. The second argument of the `MaximalBy` in the code specifies what is being used to order the eigenvalues. The first example used `Abs` (magnitude), the second example used the real part.

Comment: great thank you very much